# El formulario en JSF se envia automaticamente

Tags: jsf, primefaces

estoy haciendo un programa con jsf del lado de la vista y spring security para manejar el formulario de login.

El problema que tengo es que presiono el boton de "Iniciar Sesion" para que aparezca el formulario
pero en vez de eso aparece un mensaje de error en la parte de las urls y en la página no me aparece nada. Parece como si se ejecutara el submit del formulario de manera automática

En esta imagen se muestra el formulario que debe aparecer cuando se presiona el link de "iniciar sesion". el atributo de rendered contiene una expresión booleana.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esta imagen se muestra el enlace que sirve para que aparezca el formulario en pantalla. La página se llama logoutMenu.xhtml

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esta imagen se muestra que en la parte de la url sale error de login. Es decir que me aparece lo mismo que me aparecería si en el formulario de login introdujera un nombre o una contraseña incorrecta. Sin embargo en la pantalla no me aparece nada, pero me deberia aparecer el formulario.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esta imagen se muestra la clase que hace de controlador. Utiliza el método loadSessionForm para poder mostrar el formulario.
Este método se llama desde la página logoutMenu.xhtml a través del link.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes pegar parte del código para ver cómo lo has hecho y ver dónde está el fallo, así los demás podremos ayudarte, sino estamos a ciegas

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: Cuando mencionaban "pegar código", se referían a pegarlo _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes.